# What does this formula refer to in graph theory? $\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2}$?

Tags: graph-theory

The result is 28 but what is this number referring to?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2}$ refers to the maximum possible number of edges of a simple graph (no double edges, no loops) on $n$ vertices and with $k$ connected components.